# Activator.CreateInstance Works in Web Service ONLY if User is Logged in Locally

Tags: wcf, memory, activator

I have a WCF Service that impersonates a user and calls `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a COM Object:

```
if(impersonateValidUser(impersonatedUser,impersonatedUserDomain,impersonatedUserPassword))
    {
    try
    {
        obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Client.Application"));
    }
    catch { }
    undoImpersonation();
}
```

When I am logged on to the server locally as `impersonatedUser`, all works as expected.  `Client.exe` exists as a process, as does `Viewer.exe`.  Both are created when I activate the COM Object.

However, if I am NOT logged on locally as `impersonatedUser`, only `Client.exe` is created as a process, and I get the error:

```
The instruction at “<address>” referenced memory at "0x00000000". The memory could not be “read.”
```

My only guess is that the system doesn't allocate enough memory if the user is not otherwise logged on?  I have no other idea what the issue could possibly be.  Any suggestions?

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `Viewer.exe` is created after and somehow not allotted enough memory by your code?  Could you activate that?